# How to modify a single list item after Asynctask is done in a BaseAdapter to

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

In my main activity I display a `ListView` which uses a custom `BaseAdapter` (ThoughtListAdapter).

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new ThoughtListAdapter(this, resultingThoughts);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Every item in the `ListView` has a custom layout containing a `TextView` and two `Button`.

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_thought, null);
}

thoughtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_text_view);
likeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_like_button);
dislikeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_dislike_button);
```

When a `Button` is clicked an `AsyncTask` (AsyncPost) is called which connects to my database and makes some changes.

```
likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("LIKE CLICKED");
            Thought t = thoughtItems.get(position);
            thoughtId = t.getId();
            opinion = 1;

            AsyncPost asyncPost = new AsyncPost(activity,ThoughtListAdapter.this);
            asyncPost.execute(SHARE_THOUGHT_URL,
                    TAG_PERSON_EMAIL, "m@b.it",
                    TAG_THOUGHT_ID, thoughtId.toString(),
                    TAG_OPINION, opinion.toString());
        }
    });
```

What I need is making both `Button`-s of a list item disappear after the `AsyncTask` is done with a successful outcome. I have a method `onComplete(JSONObject json)` which elaborates the `JSONObject` returned by the `AsyncTask`. I try to make the buttons non visible inside the `onComplete` method, but this doesn't work because `onComplete()` doesn't know which exact button has been clicked.
How can I pass an instance of the exact clicked button inside `onComplete()` and make disappear only the Like and Dislike buttons of the concerned list item?

`AsyncPost` is a global `AsyncTask` used by all my other activities. I would strongly prefer to leave it alone. The `onComplete()` method functions as the `onPostExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`.
Here are the `getView()` and `onComplete()` methods inside my `BaseAdapter`, which contain all the code shown above. 
Thank you.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (layoutInflater == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_thought, null);
    }


    thoughtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_text_view);
    likeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_like_button);
    dislikeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_dislike_button);

    //thoughtItems is a list of custom ojbects (Thought)
    Thought t = thoughtItems.get(position);

    //Here i set the content of the current TextView
    thoughtText.setText(t.getText());

    //the two buttons do basically the same thing when get clicked
    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Thought t = thoughtItems.get(position);
            thoughtId = t.getId();
            opinion = 1;

            AsyncPost asyncPost = new AsyncPost(activity,ThoughtListAdapter.this);
            asyncPost.execute(SHARE_THOUGHT_URL,
                    TAG_PERSON_EMAIL, "m@b.it",
                    TAG_THOUGHT_ID, thoughtId.toString(),
                    TAG_OPINION, opinion.toString());
        }
    });

    dislikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Thought t = thoughtItems.get(position);
            thoughtId = t.getId();
            opinion = 0;

            AsyncPost asyncPost = new AsyncPost(activity,ThoughtListAdapter.this);
            asyncPost.execute(SHARE_THOUGHT_URL,
                                TAG_PERSON_EMAIL, "m@b.it",
                                TAG_THOUGHT_ID, thoughtId.toString(),
                                TAG_OPINION, opinion.toString());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onComplete(JSONObject json) {
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            if (json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS) == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Operazione non riuscita.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //if everything is good i try to make the buttons of that particular list item disappear
                likeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dislikeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG_LOG, "JSONException", e);
        }
    }
    else Toast.makeText(activity, "Errore connessione!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this would be to have something on your `Thought` object to indicate whether or not to show the buttons.

So in your `getView()` method you check this

```
likeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_like_button);
dislikeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thought_dislike_button);

Thought t = thoughtItems.get(position);
if (t.hideButtons()) {
    likeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dislikeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
else {
    likeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dislikeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

Then you would need to have your `onComplete` method return the `id` of the `Thought` object that it related to. Then inside your `onComplete` you could do

```
int id = //get your id from your JSON response
for(Thought t : thoughtItems) {
    if (t.getId() == id) {
        t.setHideButtons(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    }
}
```

By calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` it will redraw your list and when it does the check for whether it should show the buttons or not it will not show them because it was set on that thought item

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about notifyDataSetChanged(). Everything works as it should now.